# SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool when registering ML model on Azure

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-databricks, azure-machine-learning-service

Please I have my Databricks instance in a VNET. I’m trying to deploy my Machine learning model using the Azure ML workspace on Azure Container Instance (ACI).

I’m able to create an ML workspace. I get an SSLERROR when I try to register the Model using Model.register().

Using  this code -

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core.model import Model
import azureml.core
from azureml.core.workspace import Workspace
from azureml.core.model import Model

from azureml.core import Workspace
   ws = Workspace.create(name='myworkspace',
               subscription_id='<azure-subscription-id>',
               resource_group='myresourcegroup',
               location='eastus'
               )

model_reg = Model.register(model_path = “./model_dir”,
                       model_name = "ModelX",
                      workspace = ws)
```

Find below the error when I try to deploy my model.

SSL Error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='eastus.experiments.azureml.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /discovery (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')")))
```

Please note only the Azure Databricks is in a VNET on Azure. How do I resolve it and deploy my model as a webservice on ACI.

Thank you.

Comment: what version of the SDK are you on?

Comment: If it worked before or next day, most probably it was occasional azure internal issue, faced the same several time while retrieving AML workspace and it was caused by azure itself for sure.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: [Here is some guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-enable-virtual-network#azure-databricks) I found on how to use Azure ML service with an Azure DataBricks cluster that lives inside of a virtual network:

> To use Azure Databricks in a virtual network with your workspace, the following requirements must be met:
>
> - The virtual network must be in the same subscription and region as the Azure Machine Learning workspace.
> - If the Azure Storage Account(s) for the workspace are also secured in a virtual network, they must be in the same virtual network as the Azure Databricks cluster.
> - In addition to the `databricks-private` and `databricks-public subnets` used by Azure Databricks, the `default` subnet created for the virtual network is also required.
>
> For specific information on using Azure Databricks with a virtual network, see Deploy Azure Databricks in your Azure Virtual Network.

Still could be a bug -- I see you've [reported the error](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/1138) which the product team can take a look at. Meantime, Have you tried debugging locally yet? [This guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-troubleshoot-deployment) does a good job of running through common failure modes.

Comment: Yes it works for my local machine and also it works when I create/use a Databricks workspace without adding it to a VNET.

Comment: ok, looks like its a known scenario. updated answer to include a doc snippet I found. Please follow up should you have more questions

Comment: Thanks for the update Anders. So I'll add the databricks-private and databricks-public subnets and the default subnet in the Firewalls and virtual networks section of the workspace storage account as an existing Virtual Network?